# Element-wise multi-dimension array index in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am learning tensorflow, I know in numpy I can do

`a = np.random.randn(1,2,3)
a[a<0.5] = -1`

How can I do the same in tensorflow? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of [tf.less](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/less) and [tf.where](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where).

```
t1 = tf.Variable(np.random.randn(1,2,3), dtype = tf.float32)
t2 = tf.less(t1, 0.5)
t3 = tf.where(t2, tf.fill((1,2,3), -1.0), t1)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(t1))
    print(sess.run(t3))
```

Output:

```
[[[-2.36796331 -0.29641244  1.46340346]
  [-0.38756183 -0.39763084 -0.34627825]]]

[[[-1.         -1.          1.46340346]
  [-1.         -1.         -1.        ]]]
```